# How can I identify processes with high CPU usage?

Tags: windows-7, security, performance

My CPU remains from 30-40 percent even when everything is closed.  Is there a way to scan unknown/bad Windows 7 processes and apply a fix?

Norton 360 is already installed.  I just installed Malwarebytes free version to scan.

Comment: Download and run Process Explorer to see which process is eating up the CPU

Comment: 30-40% is pretty normal. I have a brand new blazing fast gaming laptop, and it's usually at 26%. It should just be the necessary system files consuming that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Performance Monitor" from Windows 7.

Open your Startmenu and search for it.

Once started, use the green + and choose what you want to monitor.